# Validation in the save_settings method of a custom fieldtype?

Tags: add-on-development, fieldtype

How does one go about including validation code associated to the `save_settings()` method in a custom fieldtype?

Basically I want to check the posted values of the fieldtype's settings before saving them and if the validation fails, I want to send the user back to the settings page again with an error message.

The `post_save_settings()` method wouldn't be of use as it is run after the settings have already been saved, or am I wrong? Returning false or an error string from `save_settings()` also does not prevent the data from being saved.

Comment: Kevin from EllisLab here. There's not a very good way at the moment. As you can see, our own form validation is just basically exit() statements, and then that doesn't even work well because the XID doesn't refresh when you go back to fix the error, so you get redirected to the CP homepage when you submit the form a second time. So it's an issue currently, and I can't give you any timelines for fixing, but I can tell you I really want to fix it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin. Thought I was going nuts or missing something completely. For now I'm just injecting some JS validation in the fields settings view but the paranoid coder in me wants to include some sort of backend validation as well :D Will be looking forward to the fix as well.